# Does jQuery work with :before and :after selectors?

Tags: jquery

For example, I have such line:

```
$('div#about_title:after').remove();
```

And it doesn't seem to work, how I can do this?

Comment: Are you talking about `::before`/`::after` pseudo elements? If so, no, there's no way to manipulate those directly from the DOM.

Comment: Another useful tidbit: The selector you're using (`'div#about_title'`) is going to perform MUCH slow than if you simply wrote `'#about_title'`. This is because id-only selectors can map directly to getElementById (which is lightning fast) and others have to be parsed through the selector engine ([sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Psuedo-elements created by `:before` and `:after` do not technically exist on the DOM, so they can not be manipulated by javascript (and consequently jQuery).

You can edit the CSS to remove them:

```
<div class="afterStuff"></div>

div.afterStuff:after {
    content: "hi";
}

$('.afterStuff').removeClass('afterStuff');
```

I would recommend adding/removing classes over directly modifying inline styling.

http://jsfiddle.net/UUPks/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.next()` instead of `:after`

Answer (score 0):

You can not use because after you're already taking element by id and id corresponds to only one element then why would not need to put after

```
$('div#about_title').remove();
```